# How can I use C# code from a C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a requirement that dictates use of an exported function from a C++ dll.

There is lots of stuff that needs to occur within the exported function, but I don't want to rewrite all of the C# code that I have written to do it.

I would like to just paste the C# code into the DLL and be done.

**NOTE:** I don't want to call a C# DLL, I want to put C# code INTO a C++ dll.

Here is the Exports.def file:

```
LIBRARY InstallCheckWin32
EXPORTS
    IsConnectionPointValid @1
    fnTest @2
```

Here is my .h File for the DLL:

```
// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the INSTALLCHECKWIN32_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. This symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// INSTALLCHECKWIN32_API functions as being imported from a DLL, whereas this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
#ifdef INSTALLCHECKWIN32_EXPORTS
#define INSTALLCHECKWIN32_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define INSTALLCHECKWIN32_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


INSTALLCHECKWIN32_API void CallCSharp();
```

Here is the .cpp file:

```
// InstallCheckWin32.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "InstallCheckWin32.h"
#include <tchar.h>


INSTALLCHECKWIN32_API void CallCSharp()
{
    // this is where I want to use C# objects
    // eg:
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
}
```

I have set the General Configuration Property "Common Language Runtime Support" to Common Language Runtime Support(/clr)

What else do I need to set to use C# code in a C++ dll?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in to a basic c++\cli tutorial yet? I bet they will even have a `DateTime.Now` example.

Comment: This DLL must be a standard Win32 dll with an exported function.  Is what I am asking even possible?

Comment: C# is not C++, I don't believe you will be able to literally just paste C# code into a cpp file and get it to compile. The C++ compiler is not going to know how to handle it. Depending on how complex it is and what exactly your C# does, I agree with Scott Chamberlain, it may be possible to rewrite it in C++/CLI without changing much.

Comment: Weird, I found this article, so maybe its do-able if you put your c# into a library.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't mix C# and C/C++ in same source file and expect compiler to somehow produce code for that.

In general mixing multiple coding languages in the same file has only limited support in some languages. With C/C++ you sometimes can mix assembly (as in `mov ax,cx`, not .Net assembly). Language/frameworks for site creation you frequently can mix in JavaScript (but not actually run at the same time)...

Fix: in most cases languages have comparable functionality/libraries - so it is frequently easier to rewrite code into one of the language. You can also interop between libraries written in different languages - how to do that depends on combination of languages. For some cases you can cross-compile source in one language to another, but generally it is limited to languages with same/similar frameworks (C++/C# is generally not falling into such bucket, but you still may find C# to C++ cross-compiler)

Comment: I have created a C++/CLI project that will do what I need to do... thank you for the insights...